# She’s always on me

Tags: word-usage, american-english

In a novel "Dead Beautiful " by Yvonne Woon a guy tells Renée about the lady who punished her:

> “Lynch loves watching people squirm. She’s always **on me** for having too much facial hair.”

I couldn't find what exactly "on me" means, though I could make out the meaning from the complete line. So is it used? And does it mean: "**shouting at or criticizing someone** "? What exactly  does it mean and is it's use common?

Comment: Yes, it's a fairly common phrase in American English and usually implies mild criticism; e.g., "Trim your beard!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be on someone in AmE means: to be constantly hassling or criticizing them for something.

"She’s always on me [criticizing me or hassling me] for having too much facial hair.”

In other words, if you are on someone about something, you want them to do something.

Here, that would be: shave off the facial hair.

It is a very common expression in American English.

[Not to be confused with the more British expression: to be on about something, which refers to constantly talking about something. In AmE, usually: going on and on about something]

Comment: But entirely equivalent to the British English expression "to be/get on", no *about* - "she's always on at me for having too much facial hair" is exactly how we would convey the meaning that you indicate.

Comment: @Lambie Could *be on someone* possibly be a short form of *be on someone's case*? *She's always on my case for having too much facial hair* – is that how you see it?

Comment: @userr2684291 They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a turn of phrase I've come across in British English, but such things are very dialect dependent. From what little context you give, I would say that this means the same as I would mean if I were to say "**she's always on *at* me**", which is a variation on the phrasal verb ["to be/go on" at somebody](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-go-on-at-sb), suggesting **nagging or persistent criticism or advice, or urging someone to do something**.

It seems likely that, in other dialects, the same meaning is conveyed with "on" rather than "on at".